# DBpedia SPARQL career of players having played for a particular team

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I would like to get the career informations for players having played for a particular team, and who is born after a certain date. I managed to do the following query :

```
select ?playerName ?year ?teamName ?matches ?goals where {
  ?player a dbo:SoccerPlayer ;
            rdfs:label ?playerName ;
            dbo:birthDate ?birthDate ;
            dbo:careerStation ?station .
  ?station dbo:years ?year ;
           dbo:team ?team ;
           dbo:team/rdfs:label ?teamName ;
           dbo:numberOfMatches ?matches ;
           dbo:numberOfGoals ?goals .
  filter (langMatches(lang(?teamName), "EN"))
  filter (xsd:date(?birthDate) > "1980-01-01"^^xsd:date)
  filter (
     ?team = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Olympique_Lyonnais>
  || ?team = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/AS_Monaco_FC>
  )
}
order by ?playerName ?year
```

My problems are :

- I only get the years corresponding to the year the player actually played for the filtered team, and I would like to have all his career
- There are a lot of line which are duplicated and I don't know why
- Some line does not correspond to my filter. Example :

  ```
  "Gaëtan Perrin"@en | 2014... | "Olympique Lyonnais Reserves and Academy"@en | 3 | 1
  ```

Thank you for your help !

Comment: do you want to get all goals of a player for a team? because you wrote *"I only get the **years** corresponding to the year the player"* - I guess it should be *"I only get the **goals** corresponding to the year the player"* - am I right? if not, can you give an example please?

Comment: Let's take Alexandre Lacazette for example. He has played for Olympique Lyonnais and he is born after 01/01/1980 so he has to be taken into account. For this player, I would like to have all this career (at Olympique Lyonnais and elsewhere)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you want: `select ?playerName ?teamName (sum(?_matches) as ?matches) (sum(?_goals) as ?goals) where {
  ?player a dbo:SoccerPlayer ; rdfs:label ?playerName ; dbo:birthDate ?birthDate ;dbo:careerStation ?station .
  ?station dbo:years ?year ;
 dbo:team ?team ;
dbo:team/rdfs:label ?teamName ;dbo:numberOfMatches ?_matches `

Comment: `;dbo:numberOfGoals ?_goals .
  filter (langMatches(lang(?teamName), "EN"))
  filter (xsd:date(?birthDate) > "1980-01-01"^^xsd:date)
  filter (?team = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Olympique_Lyonnais>
  || ?team = <http://dbpedia.org/resource/AS_Monaco_FC>
  )} group by ?playerName ?teamName order by ?playerName (max(?year))`

Comment: There is clearly a limitation, when a player played for the same team at different time periods like `2012 - 2014` and `2016 - 2017` that can't be distinguished with the above query

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What I would like is the career informations (for each player, one line for each year with the team name, the number of matches and the number of goals) for any player who has played for one these teams (at anytime during his career). Is it clearer? Thank you!

Comment: Using the `FILTER (?team ...)` in this way means you'll only see the years about that/those team(s) in the `FILTER`. You'll need to use a sub-query to get what you say you want -- which is to (1) get all players who ever played for some team(s), and (2) get the full career info for those players.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's why I tought but I don't understand how to use a join in sparql. Maybe you can help me ?

Comment: Let me recap, for players that ever played for those two teams (Lyon and Monaco), you want to get all other career stations as well? Is that correct?

Comment: This is exactly what I want ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, you have to use a subquery to get all players played for those teams and born after 1980 first. In the outer query you can then get all their career data:

```sql
select ?playerName ?year ?teamName ?matches ?goals where {

# get all players for given teams born after 1980  
{
select distinct ?player {
?player a dbo:SoccerPlayer ;           
        dbo:birthDate ?birthDate ;
        dbo:careerStation/dbo:team ?team 
filter (?team in (dbr:Olympique_Lyonnais, dbr:AS_Monaco_FC))
filter (xsd:date(?birthDate) > "1980-01-01"^^xsd:date)
}
}

# get all their career station data
  ?player a dbo:SoccerPlayer ;
            rdfs:label ?playerName ;
            dbo:birthDate ?birthDate ;
            dbo:careerStation ?station .
  ?station dbo:years ?year ;
           dbo:team ?team ;
           dbo:team/rdfs:label ?teamName ;
           dbo:numberOfMatches ?matches ;
           dbo:numberOfGoals ?goals .
  filter (langMatches(lang(?teamName), "EN"))

}
order by ?playerName ?year
```